# Paginated AngularJS posts application

Tags: javascript, performance, angular.js, ajax, pagination

I have made a small application that displays a *posts* JSON in the form of cards, with the help of AngularJS and Twitter Bootstrap 4.

The application has an interface for *pagination* and there are about 100 posts displayed on each page.

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "postsApp"
var app = angular.module("postsApp", []);

// Create controller for the "postsApp" module
app.controller("postsCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  var url = root + "/posts";
  $scope.postList = [];
  $scope.search = "";
  $scope.filterList = function() {
    var oldList = $scope.postList || [];
    $scope.postList = $filter('filter')($scope.posts, $scope.search);
    if (oldList.length != $scope.postList.length) {
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
    };
    $scope.itemsCount = $scope.postList.length;
    $scope.pageMax = Math.ceil($scope.itemsCount / $scope.perPage);
  };
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      // posts arary
      $scope.posts = data.data;
      $scope.filterList();

      // Paginate
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.perPage = 24;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
      $scope.filterList();

      $scope.currentPage = function(index) {
        $scope.pageNum = index + 1;
        $scope.startAt = index * $scope.perPage;
      };

      $scope.prevPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum > 1) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum - 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };

      $scope.nextPage = function() {
        if ($scope.pageNum < $scope.pageMax) {
          $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum + 1;
          $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
        }
      };
    });
}]);
```

```css
.posts-grid {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.posts-grid .post {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.posts-grid .text {
  padding: 8px;
}

.posts-grid .card-title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  padding: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}

.posts-grid .text-muted {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.posts-grid .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.posts-grid p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.posts-grid .post {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.pagination>li>a,
.pagination>li>a:hover,
.pagination>li>span {
  color: #585858;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination>.active>a,
.pagination>.active>span,
.pagination>.active>a:hover,
.pagination>.active>span:hover,
.pagination>.active>a:focus,
.pagination>.active>span:focus {
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: #2b7c2b;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Blog</a>
  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div data-ng-app="postsApp">
  <div class="container" data-ng-controller="postsCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 mx-auto">
        <div class="form-group search-box mt-3 px-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search post" data-ng-model="search" ng-change="filterList()">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="posts-grid" ng-if="postList.length > 0">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-ng-repeat="post in postList | limitTo : perPage : startAt">
        <div class="post">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="//lorempixel.com/450/300" />
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h3>
            <p class="text-muted">{{post.body}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="read-more">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p ng-if="postList.length <= 0" class="text-center">There are no posts</p>
    <div ng-if="pageMax > 1">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" ng-click="prevPage()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(pageMax) track by $index" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[$index == pageNum - 1]">
          <a href="#" ng-click="currentPage($index)">{{$index+1}}</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="nextPage()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.pagination > li > a').click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 500);
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

A few questions ware born in my mind recently and I did not find the answer, hence my topic here:

1. What if there ware 10 or 100 times as many posts, would the application have a performance problem (e.g. with page load)?
2. Is there a better way to paginate the application; one that would load as many items from  *posts.json* as there are displayed on *one page* (24 items), instead of the entire JSON file?
3. How would you **optimize** this application, on the front end?

Comment: Note: this post appears to be [cross-posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51566197/1575353) and also has an accepted answer there

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I think the 2 websites have different purposes. Am I wrong?

Comment: No you are not wrong - they have different purposes; I just wanted to add context for anybody else viewing this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What if there ware 10 or 100 times as many posts, would the application have a performance (page load) problem?

Try it with [10 times as many posts](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2dmb-2574). I know that just duplicates each post 10 times without modifying the unique values like *id* but it should demonstrate the performance. I can see the page links but unless I make the window full screen and zoom out (on my 24" monitor) I can't see the all the page links - e.g. the link for Page 1 is cut off, as well as anything beyond page 42.

> 2. Is there a better way to paginate the application; one that would load as many items from posts.json as there are displayed on one page (24 items), instead of the entire JSON file?

Unless the API endpoint accepts a parameter for the page size, you would likely need to utilize a server-side scripting language like Python, Ruby on Rails, PHP, C#, VB.NET, ASP, etc. which could return the specified pagesize.

> 3. How would you optimize this application, on the front end?

I don't see much that stands out as an obvious place to optimize, though I do notice that the promise callback to `$http.get(url)` has two calls to `filterList()` separated by three assignment lines:

```
$http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      // posts arary
      $scope.posts = data.data;
      $scope.filterList();

      // Paginate
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.perPage = 24;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
      $scope.filterList();
```

Is there any way to reduce the two calls to a single call there? Perhaps the first call is not needed?

Then looking at that promise callback, I see the three methods set on `$scope` there: `currentPage`, `prevPage` and `nextPage`. I would recommend moving those methods out of the callback handler, so that all it does is set the post data on `$scope` and related paging variables.

Also, I see a flaw with the jQuery code used for scrolling to the top (***which doesn't appear to be working*** because there are no elements matching the selector `.pagination > li > a` when the DOM is loaded). I tried finding an equivalent in AngularJS but found little... There is a solution I found from [this post](https://forums.asp.net/t/2094946.aspx?AngularJS+How+to+do+Animated+Scroll+To+Top+with+directives) that uses vanillaJS. I had to alter the `href` attributes on the anchors to use it.

```
$scope.scrollToTop = function() {
    var scrollDuration = 500;
    var scrollStep = -window.scrollY / (scrollDuration / 10);

    var scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if (window.scrollY != 0) {
        window.scrollBy(0, scrollStep);
      } else {
        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
      }
    }, 15);
  };
```

Then that can be used in the click handler methods:

```
  $scope.currentPage = function(index) {
    $scope.pageNum = index + 1;
    $scope.startAt = index * $scope.perPage;
    $scope.scrollToTop();
  };
```

Though in order to stop the anchor navigation, the default event handling will need to be prevented:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="currentPage($index); $event.preventDefault();">{{$index+1}}</a>
```

#### Updated code

See modified code below.

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "postsApp"
var app = angular.module("postsApp", []);

// Create controller for the "postsApp" module
app.controller("postsCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$filter", function($scope, $http, $filter) {
  var url = root + "/posts";
  $scope.postList = [];
  $scope.search = "";
  $scope.filterList = function() {
    var oldList = $scope.postList || [];
    $scope.postList = $filter('filter')($scope.posts, $scope.search);
    if (oldList.length != $scope.postList.length) {
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
    };
    $scope.itemsCount = $scope.postList.length;
    $scope.pageMax = Math.ceil($scope.itemsCount / $scope.perPage);
  };


  $scope.currentPage = function(index) {
    $scope.pageNum = index + 1;
    $scope.startAt = index * $scope.perPage;
    $scope.scrollToTop();
  };

  $scope.prevPage = function() {
    if ($scope.pageNum > 1) {
      $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum - 1;
      $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
      $scope.scrollToTop();
    }
  };

  $scope.nextPage = function() {
    if ($scope.pageNum < $scope.pageMax) {
      $scope.pageNum = $scope.pageNum + 1;
      $scope.startAt = ($scope.pageNum - 1) * $scope.perPage;
      $scope.scrollToTop();
    }
  };
  $scope.scrollToTop = function() {
    var scrollDuration = 500;
    var scrollStep = -window.scrollY / (scrollDuration / 10);

    var scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if (window.scrollY != 0) {
        window.scrollBy(0, scrollStep);
      } else {
        clearInterval(scrollInterval);
      }
    }, 15);
  };
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(data) {
      // posts arary
      $scope.posts = data.data;
      $scope.filterList();

      // Paginate
      $scope.pageNum = 1;
      $scope.perPage = 24;
      $scope.startAt = 0;
      $scope.filterList();
    });
}]);
```

```css
.posts-grid {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.posts-grid .post {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.posts-grid .text {
  padding: 8px;
}

.posts-grid .card-title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  padding: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}

.posts-grid .text-muted {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.posts-grid .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.posts-grid p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.posts-grid .post {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.pagination>li>a,
.pagination>li>a:hover,
.pagination>li>span {
  color: #585858;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination>.active>a,
.pagination>.active>span,
.pagination>.active>a:hover,
.pagination>.active>span:hover,
.pagination>.active>a:focus,
.pagination>.active>span:focus {
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: #2b7c2b;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Blog</a>
  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contacts</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div data-ng-app="postsApp">
  <div class="container" data-ng-controller="postsCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-9 mx-auto">
        <div class="form-group search-box mt-3 px-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search post" data-ng-model="search" ng-change="filterList()">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="posts-grid" ng-if="postList.length > 0">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3" data-ng-repeat="post in postList | limitTo : perPage : startAt">
        <div class="post">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="//lorempixel.com/450/300" />
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <h3 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h3>
            <p class="text-muted">{{post.body}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="read-more">
            <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p ng-if="postList.length <= 0" class="text-center">There are no posts</p>
    <div ng-if="pageMax > 1">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item"><a href="#" ng-click="prevPage(); $event.preventDefault();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
        <li ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(pageMax) track by $index" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[$index == pageNum - 1]">
          <a href="#" ng-click="currentPage($index); $event.preventDefault();">{{$index+1}}</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="nextPage(); $event.preventDefault();"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try an answer **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682728/angularjs-1-6-application-bug-turning-items-pagination-into-a-service-does-not)** on Stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: okay; Was this answer useful/helpful?

Comment: Yes. I need to improve the project further. By turning the pagination into a *service*.